# How to detect which WebPart zone is empty and hide that WebPart Zone?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part-zone

I have 2 columns and 2 row `div` structure in my custom page layout of Publishing type. I have kept 4 WebPart zones in each boxes made by `div` structure.

Now my requirement is, the box with no WebPart added should not be displayed on the page in display mode.

While searching I came to so many post like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/340/setting-displaynone-for-empty-web-part-zones)

But this is not working here.

So, my question is:

How do I detect which WebPart zone is empty?

**Note:** I am having only SharePoint designer to work with as its SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this article for solution. I think this is what you require.

https://johanleino.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/hiding-empty-web-part-zones-using-jquery/

Comment: This might answer the question but link-only answers tend to get useless once the link is deleted/gone. Kindly copy the useful information from the blog and paste it in your answer.